How can Typescript Code Repository be used like a Shared Library?
I would like to have common code management from a development perspective.
So I was able to create a Share Library for Pyspark by looking at "Share Python libraries" in the Palantir document.
But I couldn't find anything like Share Typescript libraries anywhere in the Palantir document.
I would like to search for specific values in commonly used ontologies through Palantir's Share Typescript library. Could you help me?
I simply added the Typescript Code Repository I am using to Settings > Libraries of another Typescript Code Repository, but it fails to load and an error occurs.
(However, registering and using NPM on my local computer worked normally.)
